# Which android OS versions support "Do Not Disturb" setting?

Tags: android, android-version

I am developing an app which has a feature involving the "Do Not Disturb" setting in the device.

My question is, is it sufficient to allow this feature only on API >=23 based OS (6.0 and above), or should it be supported on older OS versions? Which OS version was this setting introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "Do not disturb" mode is only available on API >= 23. So yes, it is sufficient to allow that feature only on 23+.

https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295?hl=en